# Typescript optional parameter not autocompleting

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I have a typescript function that looks like this:

```
  create(data: TypedWriteData<T>, options?: { id?: string }): Promise<string>
  create(data: TypedWriteData<T>, options?: { id?: string; type: DatabaseWriteType }): string
  create(data: TypedWriteData<T>, options?: { id?: string; type?: DatabaseWriteType }) {
    ....
  }
```

In the options, both id and type are optional, but whenever the options.type is defined, I want the function to return a string, and when it has no type, it should return a promise.

This all works fine, but then when I go to call the function, the autocomplete doesn't find the 'type' property until it's fully written, so it sort of acts like a hidden property. Is there a way that I can write the function to show this in the autocomplete?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `{ type..`

Comment: no, since it's already in the options object

Comment: please share reproducible example